# fallback webserver & dns

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, web-server

There may be solutions to this here. I've searched and I haven't been able to find them, but...

Ok I have two web servers, these servers are online all the time 24/7, once in a while I will take them down to do maintenance on them (one at a time of course) however what I'd like to do is for example if i take them both offline, I'd like to have a web server that loads a page saying "Website Offline, check back soon". Is there a way to do this Dynamically if both servers are Windows Servers?

Both servers are running 2008 R2 x64, and both servers are DNS Servers (one primary, one secondary). Hope this helps anyone looking to help me. Please let me know if you need anymore information and I'll add it here.

Comment: This is usually handled by network appliance in front of the actual web server farm. One common option is to have a load balancer or application proxy respond with a generic error when no backend servers are available. You can't have servers that aren't there handle anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both webservers are in the same network (not distributed across sites/countries), the best solution will be to put a Load Balancer device in front of the web servers, one of the best ones out there is F5 LTM, but as this is an expensive appliance, I would recommend [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu), which is an open source software package compatible with most *nix based systems.

Some useful resources for your particular scenario:

[Zero-Downtime Restarts with HAProxy](http://www.igvita.com/2008/12/02/zero-downtime-restarts-with-haproxy/)

[Easy web server Load-Balancing with HAProxy](http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2011/07/05/easy-web-serve-load-balancing-with-haproxy/)

[Creating a maintenance page for your site](http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/creating-a-maintenance-page-for-your-site)

So, you can put a Linux server with haproxy in front of those servers to load balance the incoming requests.

Comment: I see what you mean but we have a limited number of Public IP addresses, that would mean that we'd have to allocate an IP address to the machine running haproxy, and then point all records through that machine to ensure they stay up....is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. You wold only need a public IP for the machine running haproxy and update all DNS records to point to it. Also, if you have an SSL site in the web servers, you would only need one SSL certificate for the load balancer (Instead of the 2 or more that you would need without a load balancer)